# Freezing a graph as a bytes file in Tensorflow so it can be used in Unity

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am getting this error, not exactly sure what I am missing:

> TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to
>   Tensors/Variables. Not a variable:
>   Tensor("BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases:0", shape=(12,),
>   dtype=float32)

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to SO. Please have a look here in order to improve your questions (esp. formatting): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask